# How to read client side xml file using HTML5 in Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, xml, html

I am trying to load local XML file and parse it. For this I have tried writing the code and strucked here. Please someone help me to proceed further

```
function xmlSet() {
    var files = document.getElementById('files').files;
    if (!files.length) {
        alert('Please select a file!');
        return;
    }
    var start = 0;
    var stop = file.size - 1;
    var str = "";
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
        str = //Total XML string     
    };
    var xml = $.parseXML(str);
    xml.find('*').each(function() {
        // XML parsing code  
    });
}
```

Comment: What's the question? Have you read [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) and don't understand something there?

Answer (score 0):

Use the DOMParser API to parse the selected file:

```
  function readXML()
    {
    var fileString = arguments[0].target.result;
    with (new DOMParser)
      {
      var xmlDOM = parseFromString(fileString, "text/xml");
      console.log(xmlDOM.documentElement.nodeName);
      }
    }

  with (new FileReader)
    {
    var files = document.getElementById('files').files[0];
    onloadend = readXML;
    readAsText(files, "utf-8");
    }
```

**References**

- [MSDN: DOMParser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975060.aspx)
- [MSDN: XMLSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975124)
- [MSDN: FileReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh453225)